# Why does the name "central nervous system" contain 'nervous' and not 'nerves'?

Tags: adjectives, terminology, biology

I was searching for something related the central nervous system, and then it hit me: why is it called  "the central **nervous** system" and not "the central **nerves** system"? It is obviously a system of nerves - why the adjective form?

I tried searching for it online, but it's pretty hard to find anything linguistic about this term, as it is so common in biology- and medicine-related material.

Comment: Why not *nervous*? What is it about this use of *nervous* that makes it puzzling?

Comment: Perhaps because "nerves" is a noun, but an adjective -*nervous"- is required to qualify "system".

Comment: I thought that perhaps it should have been 'nerves system' (I realize it looks too weird...) in the sense of "system of the nerves". However, I just came across [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_systems_of_the_human_body), so I see it is the same for all systems in the body to be described by an adjective and not have a possessive structure, so I guess my question has no point. Should I delete it?

Comment: This isn't a bad question; just one that has a pretty clear answer: *nervous* follows the same pattern as *circulatory* (not *circulation*), *digestive* (not *digestion*), etc. You can answer your own question, using the information provided in that link.

Comment: I believe your question is the same as this one:https://english.stackexchange.com/q/538931/349876

Comment: [Nervous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nervous) (adjective): "**1 c** : of or relating to the nerves." *Nerves* is a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: I would write "the central nerve system" (in the singular) for that case.

Comment: Note that adjectives are not inflected for number, so *nerves system* where a noun is used as an adjective is not correct. It would be *central nerve system.* However, as [JB has said](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/539299/18696), the system does not merely consist of nerves.

Comment: It wouldn't be "the nerves system", just like we don't talk about a "bricks wall".  It could conceivably be "the central nerve system."  P.S. Just seen the comment by @Weather Vane

Comment: @chaslyfromUK three of us in a row agree about that ;) I like your example.

Answer (score 4):

As a biologist, but not a physiologist, I’m a little nervous answering questions about the nervous system. But if I were a psychologist I might have the nerve to say that the problem lies in the question, rather than the answer.

The answer appears simple. “Nerve” is the noun, “nervous” is the (latinate) adjective.

But the question suggests that the poster is, well, nervous because in English the adjective can have two distinct meanings — 1. Related to the nerves; 2. agitated and apprehensive (Chambers).

However this is a little unfair to the poster as I think that there is a psycholinguistic justification for his question. ‘Nervous’ does not obviously sound latinate to the general public — unlike other anatomical adjectives such as cardiac, pulmonary, ocular, for which there are common English equivalents. And in the English equivalents the *noun is used as an adjective* (heart surgery, lung disease, eye trouble).

This possible mental confusion would not have existed at the time that ‘nervous’ entered the English language in the 1660s, when it did so in its anatomical sense, being derived from the Latin, *nervus*. It was only later (1740) that its alternative and more general use arose (according to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/nervous)). Indeed the mental association that became possible after this time may have been the reason for the later (about 1830) introduction of the Greek adjective, [*neural*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=neural), into medical and scientific English. This is the basis of more modern terminology, but ‘nervous system’ was presumably too well established to be displaced by ‘neural system’ — even neurologists wouldn’t have the nerve.

Comment: You pinpointed one of the issues I was nervous about in your two distinct meanings. "Nerve system" would eliminate the second meaning, but as others have pointed out, *nervous* in your first sense makes perfect sense. Like your answer. :-)

Comment: @RichardKayser I was a little too frivolous in my answer. (I find ELU a light relief from Biology.) The psychology is a little more complex than I immediately assumed, so I have extended and moderated it a little.

Answer (score 2):

The "adjective" versus "noun" aspect is the largest part of this answer, but I would also like to add that the central nervous system also includes components that one might not necessarily refer to as "nerves" or even "nerve cells", such as structural cells or cells that facilitate nerve function without acting as a primary "nerve cell". Calling it the "nerves system" might imply that the system is comprised ONLY of nerves.